# redirect to "/" or to index.html

Tags: http, redirect, seo, httpwebrequest

Currently in my website the user can browse both to

```
www.mysite.com/index.html
www.mysite.com (which actually returns index.html)
```

I want everything to eliminate the ambuguity, e.g. either

```
www.mysite.com/index.html
```

OR

```
www.mysite.com
```

What is the best practice to use, considering

1. HTTPrequests
2. SEO

Thanks, 
p.s. if there are any other considerations besides SEO, number of HTTP request, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question was not HOW TO redirect (though, I don't know yet), but "WHAT IS BETTER? with or without the /index.html"

Comment: I think you should keep "/". See http://www.searchenginejournal.com/should-urls-in-links-use-indexhtml/4434/

Comment: Thanks. This one http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.il/2006/12/deftly-dealing-with-duplicate-content.html also seems good.

Comment: So what have you decided? 
"/" or "/index.html'